# Is there a way to expand macro based on command line arguments?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Here is the pseudocode of what i would like to do:

```
if (argv[2] != NULL)
    #define PATH argv[2]
else
    #define PATH "."
```

Comment: `#define ...` is "consumed" by the compiler (the pre-processor) when the program is created. It simply does not exist at the same time as `argv[2]` which is created by the execution environment when the executable is invoked. Suggestion: make a variable and set it as you need according to `argv[2]`, maybe `char pathstring[1000] = "."; if (argv[2]) strcpy(pathstring, argv[2]);`

Comment: No, that's impossible. The preprocessor is run before the compiler.

Comment: Instead, you could define `char *path;` and in your `if`, do `path = argv[2]` or `path = "."`.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use the preprocessor?

Comment: @klutt it was mostly a curiosity, and above all, I did not remember that obviously, the evaluation of the command line arguments took place after the preprocessor directives.